# How to assign custom class to PropertyGridControl.SelectedObject at design time

Tags: winforms, devexpress, propertygrid

How could I assign a custom class (Customer, Order, etc) to a DevExpress PropertyGridControl (or native Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid) at Design Time?
The PropertyGridControl.SelectedObject's dropdown list shows only the other Controls used in the form, but not custom fields declared by me. For instance:

```
Dim oCustomer As new Customer
```

I'd like to customize MultiEditorRows, styles, etc at design time to show my object properly.
At runtime it's as easy as:

```
myPropertyGridControl.SelectedObject = New Customer
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please excuse my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At design-time only components that exist on a form can be selected as the grid's SelectedObject. Of cause, you can make your object a Component descendant and drop it onto a form to select it. But, I don't think that you really need this. As far as I understand, you need to generate grid rows at design time to customize them. If so, it's better to use the [Rows Page](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument468) designer to manually add the required rows and customize them.

Comment: yes, I have to mark this as answered. Native WinForms PropertyGrid control allows to hack it by writing `Me.PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = New MyClass` in the hidden `Form1.Designer.vb` file, and it shows its properties in Form designer. But devexpress' one doesn't. I have to create/format all rows by hand at design time and then assign an instance at runtime. Thanks.

Comment: otherwise, there's the convenient devx's DataLayoutControl, which uses a BindingSource